Google Maps Direction API Japan - No results returned for transit
I have been working on an application that uses Google Maps Directions API.  I have been successful in getting Driving and Walking directions for Tokyo Japan.  But once I change it to Transit, I get No Route.  I have gone to Google Maps and copied the info from a transit route that it was able to make.
I then went to try out the newer Routes API.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/demo This doesn't work either even when picking validated addresses.
Am I missing something?  Does Transit just not work for Japan in either API or is there a setting I need to turn on?

From the documentation:
In which countries are transit directions available?
The Directions API and Distance Matrix API support all Google Transit partners, except those in Japan.
(from this issue in the bug tracker)

Oh crap that is what I was looking for.  This has been an issue for over 10 years and no progress really sucks.  Do you know of any alternatives?
